# Alternative formulation of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, taylor-expansion, transformation

We have a function $f(x)$ that is continuous for all $x\geqslant 0$. We were able to calculate this function as
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^n}\left[\Gamma(n) - \Gamma(n + 1, x)\right],
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Our goal is to analyze the monotonicity of this function but the problem is that I would like, if possible, to first show that
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & x = 0, \\
                     \frac{1}{x^n}\left[\Gamma(n) - \Gamma(n + 1, x)\right] &  x > 0.
       \end{cases}$$

If I'm not mistaken, to prove the second formulation holds, I need to show that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = 0.$$

But so far I have not been successful since we would get $\frac{1}{0}$. One thing I could think of was to write
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^n}\left[\Gamma(n) - n! e^{-x} \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} \right]$$ since $n$ is a positive integer but I couldn't progress further.

I also tried to expand it around $x = 0$ as a series but it didn't work. So is there a way to reformulate $f(x)$ to check if the above limit holds and later on, analyze the monotonicity of $f(x)$?

**Edit**

I have made a mistake. The function is
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & x = 0, \\
                     \frac{1}{x^n}\left[\Gamma(n + 1) - \Gamma(n + 1, x)\right] &  x > 0.
       \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

Around $x=0$, we have
$$\Gamma(n+1,x)=\Gamma(n+1)+x^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{ x^k}{(k-1)!\,\, (k+n)}$$ So, if
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^n}\left[\Gamma(n) - \Gamma(n + 1, x)\right]$$ then
$$f(x)=-\frac{(n-1) \Gamma (n)} {x^n}+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{ x^k}{(k-1)!\,\, (k+n)}$$

So, it does not seem possible to have $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = 0$ (except if $n=1$)